# what happens if I didn't preserve Object.defineProperty descriptor attributes?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

On [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) I couldn't understand this part about `Object.defineProperty descriptor` :

> Bear in mind that these attributes are not necessarily the
> descriptor's own properties. Inherited properties will be considered
> as well. In order to ensure these defaults are preserved, you might
> freeze the Object.prototype upfront, specify all options explicitly,
> or point to null with Object.create(null).

what happens if I didn't preserve descriptor attributes?
Are there unexpected things that may happen? example, please?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very peculiar recommendation IMO, only for use in extraordinarily defensive code. Taking an example:

> you might freeze the Object.prototype upfront, specify all options explicitly, or point to null with Object.create(null).

If you don't do this, then if you happen to have code that mutates `Object.prototype` (which you really shouldn't, in any sane situation), *and* the mutated `Object.prototype` adds properties used by the descriptor, those properties will be used even though they're not directly on the object. Like this:

```js
// FOR INFORMATIONAL USE ONLY
// NEVER USE THIS NEXT LINE IN REAL CODE
Object.prototype.writable = true;


// then later:
const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', { value: 'value' });
/* In normal circumstances, the resulting descriptor would be:

{
  value: 'value',
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
}

But because `writable` was inherited from Object.prototype is true, the property is writable:
*/
obj.prop = 'value2';
console.log(obj.prop);
```

A possible remedy to this is to freeze `Object.prototype` ahead of time, so that such mutation is impossible:

```js
'use strict'; // so error below is explicit
Object.freeze(Object.prototype);

// FOR INFORMATIONAL USE ONLY
// NEVER USE THIS NEXT LINE IN REAL CODE
Object.prototype.writable = true;
```

Or to make sure that the descriptor object created doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`:

```js
// FOR INFORMATIONAL USE ONLY
// NEVER USE THIS NEXT LINE IN REAL CODE
Object.prototype.writable = true;


// then later:
const obj = {};
const descriptor = Object.create(null);
descriptor.value = 'value';
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', descriptor);

obj.prop = 'value2';
console.log(obj.prop);
```

Or write out *all* values of the descriptor explicitly, without relying on the defaults:

```js
// FOR INFORMATIONAL USE ONLY
// NEVER USE THIS NEXT LINE IN REAL CODE
Object.prototype.writable = true;


// then later:
const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {
  value: 'value',
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
});
obj.prop = 'value2';
console.log(obj.prop);
```

But in any remotely sane code, none of this should be necessary, because `Object.prototype` should never be mutated to begin with.